# How to display the videos url in thumbnails?

Tags: android, gridview, video-thumbnails

I'm facing problem in showing videos in thumbnails..

From the database video link is retrieved and stored in string array.

I want to display the array of videos in thumbnails grid view. How to implement this? Its possible to display?

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

I tried this....

```
vid = new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(vid));

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
      GridView grd = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
      grd.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
      grd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
      {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,int pos,long id)
      {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "pic"+(pos+1)+"select ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
 }
   });
      return;
     private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private final Runnable context; 
     public ImageAdapter(Runnable runnable) {
           context = runnable;
    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return vid.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
           picturesView = new ImageView((Context) context);
            //Creation of Thumbnail of video
           Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(vid.get(position),0);
           picturesView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
           picturesView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
        }else {
            picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
        return picturesView;
    }
```

Comment: Initially you are displaying the images in the grid right, what exactly you want to do on tapping the grid items? On tapping the grid items video should be played in separate screen or video has to be played in the grid cell itself?

Comment: video should play in separate screen you tube videos..before that i should display in grid view list...Guide me..

Comment: No one there to help me..please tell what im doing wrong what i want to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple, instead of string array use object arraylist which has thumbnail/bitmap for the grid item and video url like given below.

```
class video
{
  Bitmap thumnail;
  String videoURL;
}
```

From database make an arraylist of this video class then use that arraylist in getview.

```
 videoList = new ArrayList<Video>();
 // populate videolist


public int getCount() 
{
    return videoList.size();
}

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ImageView picturesView;
    if (convertView == null) {
       picturesView = new ImageView((Context) context);
        //Creation of Thumbnail of video
       //Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(vid.get(position),0);
       Bitmap bitmap = videoList.get(position).thumnail;
       picturesView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        //picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
       picturesView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
    }else {
        picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
    return picturesView;
}
```

Then in the onitemclick, using the same arraylist you can get the videourl and you can play the video in separate screen.

```
 grd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,int pos,long id)
  {
     String videoLink = videoList.get(pos).videoURL;
     // pass this video link to another activity where you want to play the video
  }
});
```

Comment: im getting the videourl as JSONObject as String..How can i store the string in ArrayList<Video>

Comment: simple ..when parsing the json Object via jsonObj.getString("name_of_Field_URL") just store this in your array via add(jsonObj.getString("name_of_Field_URL"));